# deserialize XML attribute with XSD

Tags: xml, xml-serialization, xsd

I’m using XmlSerializer to deserialize complex object, using XSD auto-generated classes. But when it comes to enumeration, there is some problem,

I want some attribute to be restricted to specific values, such as:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="choiceType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="Yes"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="No" />
      <xs:enumeration value="N/A" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

But what XSD generate is only enumerations but not string with restricted values. How can I deal with that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there anybody know who to do that? Thanks!

Comment: How about posting what XSD generates. How do you expect us to know? Could _you_ reproduce this problem given only the information you have provided?